# Keyboard input stopped working after upgrading from Kinetic to Lunar

Tags: keyboard, 23.04

I had vanilla Ubuntu 22.10 running on Lenovo IdeaPad L340 without any issues. After upgrading to 23.04, my keyboard stopped working for several apps (for example Firefox and Discord).

After googling a bit, this might be something Snap related. But where and how to start debugging / fixing this issue?

Comment: Same problem here. And I'm not able to install a new kernel, because all kernels > 5.17 all freeze just at the start of booting without any error message :(

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are two options.

- Changing the kernel: Try upgrading/downgrading the kernel or booting it into a different one. You can also try installing the [mainline-kernels](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) as well, but it's best to stick with the vanilla version of the kernel.
- Complete Reinstallation: Backup if you have any valuable data, and completely wipe and reinstall Ubuntu. Restore your data if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I don't think either of these is a reasonable approach.